Admob ads not showing on previous version of signed apk release after creating a new release
I have an Android app built in Android Studio (Java) with two ad units (banner and interstitial). In the debug version, test ads were working fine, and in the release version, ads were showing occasionally, which I assumed was because the app wasn’t verified or live yet.
I released version 1.2 of my app on the Amazon App Store. After the app was live, I added the Amazon store link to AdMob, and it showed "Getting Ready" for a while.
While this was happening, I found some minor bugs in v1.2 and fixed them. I also added a retry logic in onAdFailedToLoad() to retry loading ads up to 3 times. After making these changes, I generated a signed release version but did not change the version info in AndroidManifest.xml. Let’s call this new build v1.2.1.
In this build, ads were showing in occasionally, similar to v1.2.
Later, I received an email from AdMob saying that the app is now ready to show ads. This was for v1.2 since that was the version uploaded to the Amazon store. However, when I run v1.2 now, no ads show at all. But in v1.2.1 (which wasn’t uploaded to Amazon), ads show every time with no limitation.
I’m trying to understand why the release version of v1.2 no longer shows ads, even though I received confirmation that it was ready, while v1.2.1 (the bug-fixed version) shows ads consistently. Is it normal for older versions to stop showing ads after generating a new release version, or is there something else I need to do to prevent this from happening?
Also, in build.gradle, I have set the debug version to use test ad unit IDs and the release version to use the real ad unit IDs, so I don’t have to manually change them before generating a release.
In my Admob dashboard, everything seemed fine, but the problem is it just works for v1.2.1 not v1.2.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
